# Cannot build Xamarin iOS on Microsoft Azure Hosted Agent with GRPC Core

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mono, grpc

We want to build our Xamarin iOS using Microsoft Azure Hosted agent with MacOS VM but we are having an error when it tries to "CompileToNative"

```
MTOUCH : error MT0009: Error while loading assemblies: /Users/runner/.nuget/packages/grpc.core/2.31.0/runtimes/win/native/grpc_csharp_ext.x64.dll [/Users/runner/work/1/s/ProjectName/ProjectName.iOS/ProjectName.iOS.csproj]
```

*Note: using grpc core 2.31, 2.33 will throw the same error. upgrading to 2.34 is worst and produces 106 errors*

Our yaml file.

```
pool:
vmImage: 'macOS-latest'

steps:
 # To manually select a Xamarin SDK version on the Hosted macOS agent, enable this script with the 
SDK version you want to target
# https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=871629
- script: sudo $AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY/scripts/select-xamarin-sdk.sh 6_6_0 
 displayName: 'Select Xamarin SDK version'
 enabled: true

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'


- task: XamariniOS@2
  inputs:
    solutionFile: '**/*.sln'
    configuration: 'Release'
    buildForSimulator: true
    packageApp: false
```

There are not so much information and not so much resources with the same error on the web.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you selecting a super old version of mono? Have you tried just running msbuild instead of this XamariniOS task?

Comment: @Cheesebaron The mono current version is 6.8.0 ? I just downgrade it to 6.6.0, just try if it will make a difference, but the error is still the same. We have to make it work on Microsoft hosted azure pipeline.

Comment: It is 6.12! https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/macos/macos-10.15-Readme.md#mono

Comment: @Cheesebaron Thank you for pointing it out!!! I was using macos-10.14 that is why the latest version of mono is 6.8.0. I upgraded both, but sadly, its the same error.

Comment: Have you tried the workaround mentioned here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/16310

Comment: I did. It produced 103 more errors about the grpc. so I removed it again.